# Configuring TypeScript Sublime without explicitly defining every file path

Tags: node.js, typescript, sublimetext3

Working with TypeScript and Sublime Text 3 using the [T3S package.](https://github.com/Railk/T3S) I'd like my NodeJS project to be structured like so:

```
/web.js
/views/some-view.js
/controllers/some-controller.js
[...]
/src
/src/web.ts
/src/views/some-view.ts
/src/controllers/some-controller.ts
```

In other words, I want all my `.ts` to be under `/src` and compile to individual `.js` files under `/`.

How can I configure T3S to compile my `.ts` files like this, without explicitly defining each and every `.ts` file in my `sublime-project` file?

If I cannot use T3S's build system to accomplish this, then is there a way to disable T3S's build system? Instead I'd make a Ruby filesystem watcher and compile every time a file is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Instead I'd make a Ruby filesystem watcher and compile every time a file is changed.

There are already plenty of grunt plugins for TypeScript. E.g. `grunt-ts`. The option you need is `--outDir` : https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts#compiler-support

Comment: That is very helpful, thanks. I also found how to turn off TS3's build system (delete `Typescript.sublime-build`.) If nobody has a solution for this using T3S's build system in a few days time I'll check this off as the answer.

Comment: Update: this is the preferred solution. Grunt is great. Among other things, it can compile ts/sass/etc on heroku deployments to keep compiled code out of the repo.